# Create new patio door in basement by cutting concrete

Tags: concrete, doors, basement, framing, patio

My basement has about 2.5 ft of concrete along the wall. The reason is that the outside is a slope/hill and that 2.5" depth is just dirt. I like to install a patio door to my backyard 60x80 which is a typical size. My question is if I cut the concrete in the bottom of the wall, what do I have to consider?

My picture below:

[image]

For example, do I need to build a concrete foundation underneath and extend it out by digging the clearance area outside? How do I deal with the king stud (just two 2x4 enough?) and how is the requirement for header?

Answer (score 1):

I would hire a structural engineer or an architect to draw up plans so you know exactly what you will need to do. You need to know just what you can cut and the loads involved including any prep work and temporary building support.

Comment: That is obviously the right thing to do but I just want to get some ideas ahead